# FISCAL YEAR in oracle sql loader - control file

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a file having data as mentioned below

```
 1  John  Class1
 2  Mohr  Class2
 3  Rudy  Class3
 4  Clan  Class4
```

TABLE1 has 4 columns:

```sql
ROLL_NO     VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
NAME        VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL,
CLASS       VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
FISCAL_YEAR VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
LOAD_DATE   TIMESTAMP(3)
```

The above file data needs to load into the table TABLE1 through control file i.e.

```sql
LOAD DATA
APPEND PRESERVE BLANKS
INTO TABLE TABLE1 TERMINATED BY "\t"
TRAILING NULLCOLS
( 
 ROLL_NO,
 NAME,
 CLASS,
 FISCAL_YEAR "TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')"
)
```

If we load the above file data
between July 1st 2021 and June 30th 2022, the fiscal year should populate as 2022.

If loaded between July 1st 2022 and June 30th 2023, fiscal year should be 2023.

What is the change needs to be done in above query in FISCAL_YEAR line?

Answer (score 1):

Just need some arithmetical computations in order to determine the format for fiscal year such as

```sh
LOAD DATA
...
 fiscal_year  "TO_CHAR(sysdate,'yyyy')+CEIL(TO_CHAR(sysdate,'mm')/6)-1"
)
```

where applying `CEIL()` function after division would return

**1** for months between **1** and  **6**,

**2** for months between **7** and **12**,

then substract ***1*** to get **0** or **1** to be added to *the current year* value